# Caffe: Check failed: MaxTopBlobs() >= top.size() (2 vs. 3) Data Layer produces at most 2 top blob(s) as out

Tags: caffe

I am trying  to train on Cifar100, and as you know it has two labels, coarse and fine. This is my data layer :

```
name: "CIFAR100_full"
layer {
  name: "cifar"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "coarse_label"
  top: "fine_label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
    mean_file: "examples/cifar100/mean.binaryproto"
    mirror: true
  }


  data_param {
    source: "examples/cifar100/cifar100_train_leveldb"
    batch_size: 100
    backend: LEVELDB
  }
}
layer {
  name: "cifar"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "coarse_label"
  top: "fine_label"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  transform_param {
    mean_file: "examples/cifar100/mean.binaryproto"
  }
  data_param {
    source: "examples/cifar100/cifar100_test_leveldb"
    batch_size: 50
    backend: LEVELDB
  }
}
```

and this is how the last layers look like :

```
layer {
  name: "accuracy"
  type: "Accuracy"
  bottom: "ip1"
  bottom: "coarse_label"
  bottom: "fine_label"
  top: "accuracy"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "ip1"
  bottom: "coarse_label"
  bottom: "fine_label"
  top: "loss"
}
```

What is the problem here? I'm sure caffe layers support multiple output blobs; what am I missing here?

I am currently forced to use `HDF5Data`, which doesn't provide any transformation capabilities such as mean-subtraction and mirroring. If I'm stuck at using HDF5, how can I do mean-subtraction and mirroring now? Is there any preprocessing layers in caffe that I can use to make up for using hdf5data layer instead of leveldb or lmdb layers?

Comment: How did you create the `examples/cifar100/cifar100_test_leveldb`? can you create a leveldb with multiple output labels?

Comment: I modified the convert_cifar_data and everything seemed fine. 
there is not much difference between the two except the 5(10k) training batch-data files vs 1 big(50k) training batch-data in cifar10 and cifar100 respectively. 
and in cifar100 I had two labels instead of one label which was the case for cifar10.   there was no error in the process so to speak of!

Comment: AFAIK caffe `"Data"` layer only supports one or two outputs. I never came across a case with three, and this is what the error message tells you

Comment: @Shai: Thanks, good to know, do you by the way know if this is a limitation of the leveldb/lmdb format (database) or the caffe interface? and can it be resolved or you  think I'm better stick to the hdf5data for such things.
(the problem with hdf5 is its not performant compared to leveldb/lmdb if im not mistaken, I'd appreciate any guidance in this regard)

Comment: I am not familiar with leveldb/lmdb, I expect them to be quite versatile. The point is that caffe stores [`Datum`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L30) data types in leveldb/lmdb and expects to read such data in the `"Data"` layer. As you can see the `Datum` type is restricted to 3D data and a **single** integer label. I suppose changing this default behavior would require extensive changes to caffe.

Comment: @Shai I did exactly this. I created a cifar100 lmdb by having three fields. 1. Data 2. label (which is coarse label, 20 categories) 3. label2 (which is fine label, 100 categories). I could create lmdb after changing the `Datum` definition. Now I am running a normal caffe network, everything seems to be fine (remember, now Datum is changed). However, when I try to train a network with `Data` layer having three fields (`Data`, `label`, `label2`), caffe gives error: it can have max two blobs. Obviously I can go around by having `label2` in `.h5` format maybe. But I am thinking of an elegant way.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar it is not enough to add a field to `Datum`, you need to change source code of `"Data"` layer to read this extra field. See [`data_layer.cpp`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/data_layer.cpp) that explicitly reads only one label from `Datum`.